# Backward Stability solving linear system with unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point, unitary-matrices

Let $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a unitary matrix that can be exactly stored in floating point arithmetic. Suppose we want to solve the following linear system:
\begin{equation}
Qx=b
\end{equation}
Given that $Q$ is unitary, the simplest solution is $x=Q^{*}b$. In floating point arithmetic $Qfl(Q^{*}b)$ is not exactly $b$. It turns out that exist $||\delta Q|| = O(\epsilon_{machine})$ such that
\begin{equation}
(Q + \delta Q)fl(Q^{*}b)=b
\end{equation}

This result is stated without  proof on the book Numerical Linear Algebra (Trefthen and Bau) in chapter 16.

I tried to formulate this as the problem of finding $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, such that
\begin{equation}
Afl(Q^{*
}b)=b
\end{equation}
But I was not able to show that $A=Q + \delta Q$ for some $\delta Q$ with $||\delta Q||=O(\epsilon_{machine})$ is the solution for that problem.

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem. Start with the backward stability of the matrix-vector product: $\mathrm{fl}(Q^*b)=(Q+\delta Q)^*b$, $\|\delta Q\|_2\leq cu\|Q\|_2=cu$. Then premultiply with $Q+\delta Q$.

Comment: But how do you know that $ Q + \delta Q$ still unitary?

Comment: Nothing indicated that this would be required. This would also require that $\|\mathrm{fl}(Q^*b)\|_2=\|b\|_2$ otherwise no such unitary $Q+\delta Q$ would exist.